# InDesign GREP everything between two consecutive returns and a digit(or)return

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, grep

Say I have some text in the following format:

[image: Text before formatting]

What I am trying to style, using GREP, is the beginning of every new paragraph (that comes after an empty line), until a digit *or* return is reached, so that it would look something like this:

[image: Text after formatting]

I've been using [regexr](http://regexr.com) to try and find a solution, but it appears not be 100% compatible with InDesign's GREP utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer:

The problem is that using a paragraph break for every new line means that every line is a paragraph and using GREP paragraph styles you can only target a single paragraph. Theres no way to tell if you are on the first line because every line is the first line. The only way to get around that would be to test if the paragraph before is empty.. which I don't think is possible.

If changing the paragraph breaks to soft breaks you can use this:

```
(?<!\n).*?(?=\d|\n)
```

If changing the breaks isn't an option I havn't got a workaround for the paragraphs without numbers but you can target just the ones with using this:

```
^.*?(?=\d)
```

---

### Original Answer:

```
^.*?(?=\d|\n)
```

An explanation -

`^` matches the beginning of the paragraph

`.` matches any character

`*?` matches 0 or 1 time (so we only match up to the first digit)

`(?=)` looks ahead (matches up to but not including what's in the parenthesis)

`\d` matches any digit

`|` OR

`\n` matches a line break

---

For reference, All of this can be found on the [InDesign help](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/find-change.html).

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but I'm afraid it's not right. This catches absolutely everything that precedes the final paragraph. So it would style everything up to (but not including) "vim at omittam urbanitas scribentur" in my example above.

Comment: OK - I tried `^.*?(?=\d|\n)` (not \r as in your example) and that's _very_ close. It's not working for the third paragraph in my example though

Comment: Strange, I'll have to try once I can open ID later.

Comment: Appreciated. And, just to be clear, the only place it's failing is the third paragraph; it doesn't style the first line, but it does the subsequent ones until a digit is reached.

Comment: How are you doing the new lines, are they paragraph breaks or soft line breaks?

Comment: They're all paragraph breaks - this will be handed to a client, so I'm having to KIS as possible for them.

Comment: If they're paragraph breaks can you try replacing `\n` with `$`?

Comment: That catches everything except for the digits and contained full-stops.

Comment: OK, well I'll have to come back to it once I'm back at my computer in an hour or two.

Comment: Indesign bugs with control characters in certain matches quite consistently

Comment: As much as I don't like it, this answer seems, to the best of my knowledge, to be correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a GREP based solution, but maybe it's good enough for you. It would require to change your paragraph breaks into line breaks (which, given the context, would be the correct way to go?).

Just use a nested line style, and it'll style the first line of every paragraph, no matter what is there.

[image: nested line style]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it doesn't quite fit my criteria though, as it styles everything on the first line, not just everything up to the first digit. Out of interest though, how do you specify a line break, rather than a paragraph break?

Comment: Oh you're right! Absolute slip of the mind, sorry about that. I'll take a closer look at GREP, I was unable to target what you need in my tests. You can do line breaks by `shift + return` instead of just `return`