# Indesign GREP capture only next line

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I'm trying to GREP-match words on a line starting with a specific word:

```
Contact Person   Walter Einstein
Company   ACME Corp
Website   acme.com
```

Here, I would want to match the first words before the tab after the line starting with `Contact Person`.

I need this to automatically apply a character style which applies a greater leading to insert some space between the Company Person line and the next one, which doesn't always read 'Company'.

In the paragraph style, I made a GREP Style to apply my Char. Style but it doesn't work yet.

It's something like this:

```
(?m)(?<=Contact\sPerson\t)(?:.*~b)(^.*$)`
```

So this should be a positive lookbehind to match "Contact Person" and the following tab `(?<=Contact\sPerson\t)`, then an ignored group till the end of the line `(?:.*~b)`, and then a match for the whole next line `(^.*$)`.

I also experimented with (?s) Single line mode but couldn't manage to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i think I found the answer to why this is not working:
[InDesign GREP everything between two consecutive returns and a digit(or)return](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65353/indesign-grep-everything-between-two-consecutive-returns-and-a-digitorreturn?rq=1)

*Entering a GREP into a paragraph style is only affecting this one paragraph.* If there are standard returns / breaks (no soft breaks) the GREP only searches within this paragraph.

---

One alternative could be to apply the greater Leading to the respective line (in this case "Contact Person"..) and add a **baseline shift** to shift the whole line up again.

---

If this paragraph contains multiple lines it is possible to shift the whole paragraph by applying different Character Styles:

**First line**:

- Character style: More leading (e.g. 22pt), Baseline shift: 11pt
- GREP: `Contact\sPerson\t.*`

**Lines in paragraph after that**

- Character style: Baseline shift: 11pt
- GREP: `(?m)(?<=Contact\sPerson\t)(?:.*~b).*`